# Is it possible to make dependent picklist work in VisualForce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I need help to display a dependent picklist in Visualforce page.
I have two picklist fields which are dependent fields. I want to show them on VF page and make picklist dependent.

Is there any way to do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Controller should look like this

```
 public String selected1
 public String selected2

...

public List<SelectOption> getList1(){
List<SelectOption> opt= new List<SelectOption>();
opt.add(new SelectOption('a', 'a');
opt.add(new SelectOption('b', 'b');
}
public List<SelectOption> getList2(){
List<SelectOption> opt= new List<SelectOption>();
if(selected1 == 'a') opt.add(new SelectOption('aa', 'aaa');

if(selected1 == 'b') opt.add(new SelectOption('bb', 'bb');
}
```

And page

```
...
<apex:selectList value="{!selected1}" size="1" multiselect="false" >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!List1}" >
<apex:actionSupport reRender="list2" event="onchange"/>
</apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:selectList id=list2" value="{!selected2}" size="1" multiselect="false">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!List2}" >
</apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
...
```